# Чтение из бд FireBase

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase

Как вывести на экран определенных `child` из базы данных FireBase?
Я создаю объект ссылки на базу:

```
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
```

Инициализирую:

```
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Затем ставлю слушатель:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.child("Рецепты").getValue(String.class);
            text.setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Логи указывают на эту строчку: `String value = dataSnapshot.child("Рецепты").getValue(String.class);`
ЛОГИ:

```
03-14 19:11:22.907 30046-30046/com.example.user.firebaseexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.user.firebaseexample, PID: 30046
                                                                              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.example.user.firebaseexample.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:40)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5927)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:819)
```

Json бд:

```
    {
  "Рецепты" : {
    "Салат" : {
      "id" : 0,
      "Ингридиенты" : "Морковь, картофель, лук, укроп",
      "Описание" : "Описание продукта"
    }
  }
}
```

Как же тогда реализовать это?

Comment: если не доходит, значит вызывается onCancelled и там пишет ошибку. Либо интернет выключен/очень медленный и просто не может выполниться getValue(String.class).

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в DatabaseError, если onCancelled вызывается

Comment: @Maxgmer погуглил, первоначальная проблема оказалась в разрешениях бд, все там поправил - теперь неавторизированные пользователи тоже могут читать бд. Но появилась новая проблема я добавил ее в вопрос

Comment: покажите json своей базы данных

Comment: @Maxgmer `{
  "Рецепты" : {
    "Салат" : {
      "id" : 0,
      "Ингридиенты" : "Морковь, картофель, лук, укроп",
      "Описание" : "Описание продукта"
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: У вас под рецептами Pojo объект, у вас есть класс Рецепт, с полями id, Ингридиенты, описание?

Comment: @Нет... Если я создам подобный класс как будет выглядеть конструкция вывода данных из базы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firebase Database** хранит данные в виде **Json**, которые 'под капотом' десериализуются (превращаются в объект) с помощью **Gson**. **Gson** библиотека требует **POJO**, который она создает и заполняет на основе **Json** данных.

---

Вам нужно создать класс, например Recipe, с полями id, ingredients, description. Затем просто прочитать **json** так:

```
Recipe tastyRecipe = dataSnapshot.child("Рецепты").getValue(Recipe.class);
```

---

Тут есть [пример cоздания POJO](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/data-persistence/firebase-writing-pojos).

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Нужно будет писать dataSnapshot.child("Рецепты").child("Салат").child("Описание").getValue(String.class). Я бы в "Рецепты" советовал писать массив с объектами Recipe, а так же добавить в класс Recipe поле тип, которое уже будет говорит, салат это либо что-то еще. У вас так спроектирована база, что не получится пройтись по "Рецептам", тк вы можете не знать след названия объекта. Если вы запишите массив, на том месте будет номер от 0 до n, где N - длина массива, который вы писали в "Рецепты"